# Cropping a System.Windows.Shapes Rectangle from an image

Tags: c#, wpf, crop, cropimage.net

I want to crop a rotated Rectangle from an image. What I want to do is something like that :

```
 System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle rect = new System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle();
 // rect.RadiusX = ...; // rect.Height = ....; ..
  rect.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(angle);
```

and then crop this rectangle from Image. 
All codes that I have found cropped a System.Windows.Drawing rectangle from the image.But, I need to crop a System.Windows.Shapes to apply the rotate Transform which is not applicable with System.Windows.Drawing Rectangle.

Comment: Can you rotate the image, then crop?

Answer (score 3):

Since your question lacked some code. So as far as I have understood, the given method would provide you with appropriate results. If the answer is not upto your mark, then please elaborate the question statement more.

```
  public static Bitmap CropRotatedRect(Bitmap source, Rectangle rect, float angle, bool HighQuality)
    {
        Bitmap result = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(result))
        {
            g.InterpolationMode = HighQuality ? InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic : InterpolationMode.Default;
            using (Matrix mat = new Matrix())
            {
                mat.Translate(-rect.Location.X, -rect.Location.Y);
                mat.RotateAt(angle, rect.Location);
                g.Transform = mat;
                g.DrawImage(source, new Point(0, 0));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Hope that helps.